# Best way to do operations in np.matrix with conditions on the indexes

Tags: python, numpy, loops, numpy-ndarray

I am looking for the best way to perform operations in numpy matrices that depend on conditions on the indices.

The matrix I am working on is a symmetric square matrix, in particular it is a weighted adjacency matrix.

At the moment I have three nested loops, which is computationally expensive.

The code below records how I am performing the operations and what the conditions are during the execution of the loops.

```py
# matrix is a numpy.matrix square matrix, in particular a weighted adjacency matrix
result_vector = []
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    aux = 0
    for j in range(matrix.shape[0]):
         if j != i:
            for k in range(matrix.shape[0]):
                if k != j:
                    aux += (matrix[i,j]*matrix[i,k])*(1 - matrix[j,k])
    result_vector.append(aux)
result_vector = np.array(result_vector)
```

I tried to use the [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), but due to the subtraction in the operation I was not successful.

Is there any way to perform the operations while avoiding the loops?

Comment: First it's best to stick with normal numpy arrays; Use of `np.matrix` is discouraged, since it's often more confusing than helpful.  `@` is the matrix multiplication operator.  Replacing your `if` logic may be tricky, at least not without thoroughly visualizing what's happening.  It may help to make one or more `mask` arrays that are true or false on/off the diagonals.  Replacing loops requires thinking about operations on the whole arrays, as opposed to element-by-element.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with `einsum`. You can use the function with any arrays you want in a single call, meaning that the subtraction can be temporarily stored as a new array and used in `einsum`. You need to be careful though to somehow account for the fact that `einsum` goes through all indices, so your constraints must be enforced manually.

```python
def func2_einsum(matrix):
    # Create helper array
    one_minus_matrix = 1-matrix

    # For the subexpression matrix[i,k])*(1 - matrix[j,k])
    # Save the result for any i, j, k
    T = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', matrix, one_minus_matrix)
    # Save the result for j == k
    T_j_eq_k = np.einsum('ij,jj->ij', matrix, one_minus_matrix)
    # Enforce j != k
    T = T - T_j_eq_k
    # Enforce i != j
    np.fill_diagonal(T, 0)

    # Compute & return the full expression matrix[i,j] * T[i,j]
    return np.einsum('ij,ij->i', matrix, T)
```

A bit of benchmarking against your loop-based method shows that the `einsum` approach is up to 3 orders of magnitude faster (depending on N, the size of the array).

```python
N = 3
A = np.random.rand(N, N)

%timeit func1_loops(A)
15.6 us ± 248 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit func2_einsum(A)
12.1 us ± 64.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```python
N = 10
A = np.random.rand(N, N)

%timeit func1_loops(A)
708 us ± 8.41 us per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit func2_einsum(A)
13.2 us ± 172 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```python
N = 100
A = np.random.rand(N, N)

%timeit func1_loops(A)
792 ms ± 2.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loops each)
%timeit func2_einsum(A)
439 us ± 1.99 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```